# Как построить сетку с одним большим элементом?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, float

Подскажите, как реализовать такую сетку?

Использую Flexbox без всяких дополнительных обёрток.

Или лучше использовать Float?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На grid такое легко реализовать. Почему не использовать grid ?

Answer (score 2):

На float'ах будет так:

```css
section {
  margin-right: -1em;
}

div {
  width: calc((100% - 3em) / 3);
  float: left;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.large {
  width: calc(2 * (100% - 3em) / 3 + 1em);
  height: 7em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class=large></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: А в заголовке вопроса можно вместо "такую сетку" , что-то более поясняющее, но также не менее лаконичное?

Comment: @0xdb, ну я попробовал, но ты мог бы и сам ;)

Comment: Я тоже попробовал, но увы, красноречия не хватило.

Answer (score 1):

Хоть в условии упоминался чистый Flex, но  ИМХО так (на CSS Grid) красивее:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    grid-template-areas: "A B C" "D D E" "D D F";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.container>div {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.A {
    grid-area: A;
}

.B {
    grid-area: B;
}

.C {
    grid-area: C;
}

.D {
    grid-area: D;
}

.E {
    grid-area: E;
}

.F {
    grid-area: F;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="A">A</div>
        <div class="B">B</div>
        <div class="C">C</div>
        <div class="D">D</div>
        <div class="E">E</div>
        <div class="F">F</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Простая версия через grid:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  height: 10em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.large {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class=large></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Основа

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.h150 {
  height: 150px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <section class="col">
    <section>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
    <div></div>
  </section>

  <section class="col">
    <div class="h150"></div>
    <div class="h150"></div>
    <div class="h150"></div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Использую обертки я смогу построить такую  сетку,хотелось бы обойтись без них

Answer (score -1):

Исходя из задачи можно так, но такое решение не самое лучшее.

```css
.el--a{
  width: 510px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.el--a > *{
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
.el__150{
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  clear: both;
}
.el__320{
  height: 100px;
  width: 320px;
  clear: both;
}
.el__150_float{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="el--a">
  <div class="el__150"></div>
  <div class="el__150"></div>
  <div class="el__150"></div>
  <div class="el__320"></div>
  <div class="el__150"></div>
  <div class="el__150 el__150_float"></div>
</div>
```